# Deep Layout Parsing Invalid argument

Tags: python

I've been trying to run layout parser example from here https://layout-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/deep_layout_parsing/index.html

The problem is that when I try:

```
model = lp.Detectron2LayoutModel('lp://PubLayNet/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/config',
                                 extra_config=["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST", 0.8],
                                 label_map={0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 3:"Table", 
                                 4:"Figure"})
```

I get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\user/.torch/iopath_cache\\s/f3b12qc4hc0yh4m\\config.yml?dl=1.lock'
```

Originally, `config.yml` was not in the expected folder. But downloading it did not solve the problem.

I would appreciate a solution for this, or an alternative suggestion if it exists.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Windows10 file naming error
A fix for this is to clone and modify iopath

git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/iopath --single-branch --branch v0.1.8

Change:  *iopath/iopath/common/file_io.py*

class:
*HTTPURLHandler;*

method:
*_get_local_path line 753*

from this:

> filename = path. Split("/")[-1]

to this:

> filename = parsed_url.path.split("/")[-1]

Then call:

*pip install -e iopath*

See: https://github.com/Layout-Parser/layout-parser/issues/15#issuecomment-819546751